# Excel, return row and column values based on found text from entire sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say that I have an excel sheet that looks like this:

[image]

I need to find any cell with the value "E" and return the values from the first column in that row and from the first row in that column.

For example, in this case, the expected output would be `February 3`.

I have been able to use `HLOOKUP` and `VLOOKUP` to do similar things before but I was always searching for text in a single row or column while here, I need to search the whole table for the values.

Any way I can do this?

Note that I have no control over the format of the spreadsheet and yes, I totally agree that this is not a good format for storing and working with this data.

Comment: Where is expected output? In a cell or bunch of cells using a formula - or with VBA and a screen message?

Comment: @dbmitch ideally I'd like to use a formula in a cell on a separate sheet, but I could put it on the same sheet if needed think of a cell labeled date on a another sheet that needs to show the output described

Comment: I guess what I mean is how will the finished product look? Are you looking at a single column of all values - or a grid that matches your "E" grid, or one cell with concatenated date values. A visual would help (with more than one example E)

Comment: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/516742-how-return-results-position-2d-array.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing your Example

[image]

is in `Sheet1`, then the formulas:

```
{=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$1000,INT(SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B$2:$K$10="E",ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$K$10)+COLUMN(Sheet1!$B$2:$K$10)/1000),ROW($A1))))}
```

and

```
{=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$ALK$1,,RIGHT(TEXT(SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B$2:$K$10="E",ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$K$10)+COLUMN(Sheet1!$B$2:$K$10)/1000),ROW($A1)),"0.000"),3))}
```

both copied downwards will get

[image]

in another sheet.

First formulas are in `B2` and `C2` here.

Both formulas are array formulas. Put it into the cell without typing the curly brackets. Then press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to confirm. Now the curly brackets should appear.

The search range `Sheet1!$B$2:$K$10` within the formulas can be extended until `Sheet1!$B$2:$ALK$999`. But the bigger that range is the worse will be the performance.

The approach is to get a list of numbers (row number + column number / 1000) where the "E" appears in the search range. That is row number as integer part and column number as decimal part where 1 will be 0.001, 2 will be 0.002, ..., 999 will be 0.999. Then using `Small` to get those  numbers from smallest to biggest. Then get the real row number by getting the integer part. And get the real column number from the last 3 digits.

To using the last three digits of the calculated decimal number as column number we must ensure that there are three digits as decimal places in all cases. So we must use formatting `0.000`. For this we can use `TEXT` function.

Comment: Nice approach to problem

Comment: I noticed a bug/flaw in using the column number / 1000 method:

Let's say if your data landed on row 2, column 10, the formula would return 2.010, which gets reduced to 2.01, representing row 2, column 1.

I suppose one solution is to just swap the column to the integer portion of the formula when working in column C.

Comment: @Wolfspirit: You are right. I have improved my answer.